# curl www.google.com works differently when the url is called from browser directly

Tags: curl

When I type `curl www.google.com` in the terminal I get the below reply. But when I type the similar url([www.google.com](http://www.google.com)) in browser(chrome) I get redirected to [www.google.co.in](http://www.google.co.in)

Why am I not able to see the below HTML when I call the same URL from browser?

```
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.co.in/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Browsers automatically follow redirects, so that intermediate page will only be available for a microscopic fraction of time before the `.co.in` version of the page is loaded. CURL, by default, does **NOT** follow redirects, so you get that intermediate page instead.

Answer (score 22):

```
curl -L http://www.google.com
```

Will make curl follow redirects and you will recieve actual search page.

Comment: -L here refers to the location?